# How to Breakdown Facebook Custom Events by Parameter in Facebook Analytics?

Tags: facebook-pixel, facebook-analytics

I am trying to Breakdown Facebook Custom Events by Parameter but they are shown as All Others in Facebook Analytics.

I have successfully installed the Facebook Pixel base code and applied Custom Events to track link clicks on a page in my website.  Events are being logged successfully with the correct custom parameters. The concern is when I tried Facebook Analytics Breakdowns. Even if I specify the custom parameter in the Breakdown, the result still shows as "All Others"

```
<script>
function onClickLink1() {
    fbq('trackCustom', 'Link_Click', {clickloc: 'Link1', content_name: 'Content1'});
};
</script>

<script>
function onClickLink2() {
    fbq('trackCustom', 'Link_Click', {clickloc: 'Link2', content_name: 'Content2'});
};
</script>
```

I expect that the Breakdowns will give me the counts either by clickloc which are Link1 and Link2 or by content_name which are Content1 and Content2.  However, Facebook Analytics is grouping all of them as 'All Others'.

Please let me know if I am missing anything.  Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 2):

When you do a Breakdown and the message shown is 'All Others' means the filter that you're viewing, or the audience that you're viewing for a given time period, may not be large enough.

Try adjusting the conditions of your filter to increase the number of people represented in your filtered view. You can also try increasing the time interval you're viewing.

https://www.facebook.com/help/analytics/885102478239387